# Некорректно показывается "Backgroung-image"

Tags: html, css, frontend, background

Это мой первый проект после короткого обучения и вот появились первые вопросы. На сайте некорректно отображается "background-image", а точнее появляется высотой с написанный текст и длинной в сайт. Как исправить?

```css
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -102px;
}

.all {
  background-image: url(https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/709/293555-alexfas01.jpg);
  /* Ахыхаыха , заряжена картинка на улучшение зрения ))00 */
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #2585;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Marck Script", cursive;
  line-height: 140%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-right {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
}

header,
#footer {
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #540588ba;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding: 1%;
}

#footer {
  border-top: 2px solid purple;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #BF5ED0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #3A004B;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all.5s ease;
}

a:active {
  color: #C4FFFF;
}


/*  Videlenie  */

::selection {
  background: #FFDEE3;
  color: #000000;
   ::-moz-selection {
    background: #FFDEE3;
    color: #000000;
     ::-webkit-selection {
      background: #FFDEE3;
      color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
    <a href="index2.html" title="Главная страница" class="logo">
      <center> ~Ууу , красивый текст </center>
    </a>
  </header>
  <div class="all">
    АЕЕЕ
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Ну тут тип инфа , что если скопипастишь без ссылки на источник , то тебя посадят на пятилитровую банку из - под бабушкиных огурцов
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uonrytv0/1/)

Comment: фон всегда берёт высоту контейнера где находится, если в конейнере вы ничего не будете ставить, придётся установить значение min-height: 640px; для .all, если я правильно понял вопрос )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `display: flex;` `flex-direction: column;` для обертки и `flex-grow: 1;` для блока, который надо растягивать. [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/zc2t9sjq/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -102px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.all {
    background-image: url(https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/709/293555-alexfas01.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

    flex-grow: 1;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    color: #2585;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "Marck Script", cursive;
    line-height: 140%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top-right {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto \9;

}

header, #footer {
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #540588ba;

}

header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    padding: 1%;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 2px solid purple;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    color: #BF5ED0;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
}

a:hover {
    color: #3A004B;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
}

a:active {
    color: #C4FFFF;
}

/*  Videlenie  */

::selection {
    background: #FFDEE3;
    color: #000000;

::-moz-selection {
    background: #FFDEE3;
    color: #000000;

::-webkit-selection {
    background: #FFDEE3;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Текст">
 <title>Ещё текст</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css">
 <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
  <header>
     <a href="index2.html" title="Главная страница" class="logo">
        <center> ~Ууу , красивый текст </center>
      </a>
  </header>
  <div class="all">
     АЕЕЕ
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
    Ну тут тип инфа , что если скопипастишь без ссылки на источник, то тебя посадят на пятилитровую банку из - под бабушкиных огурцов
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В таком случае не видно подвала сайта , как пофиксить ?

Comment: Не видно из за вашего margin: 0 auto -102px у #wrap. Уберите его и все будет хорошо